# Why is npm install failing because of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, node.js, macos

I'm running npm install on my Mac OSX 10.8.3
But it is failing with the error:

```
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch <path-to-xcode>, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.
```

I can't figure out why. Can someone assist? 
Why is Xcode needed by npm?

FYI, here is the full output of my npm command: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/10411252

And here is the contents of my package.json file: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/10411480

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because the item you are installing has a native (c/c++) component to it that needs to be compiled.

To do this you need to install XCode and the XCode command line tools.  XCode is available from the OSX App Store.  The command line tools are installable from within the XCode environment I believe.